# Create a boxplot with boxpoints of different shapes with plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
etf_id<-c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c","d","e")
factor<-c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
normalized<-c(-0.048436801,2.850578601,2.551666490,0.928625186,-0.638111793,
              -0.540615895,-0.501691539,-1.099239823,-0.040736139,-0.192048665,
              0.198915407,-0.092525810,0.214317734,2.550478998,0.024613778)
df<-data.frame(etf_id,factor,normalized)
```

I wonder if I can create a box plot with several legends (`color` as `etf_id` and `shape` as `factor`) like the one below but with `plotly()` and not `ggplotly()`. More specifically I need my `boxpoints` to get their `shape` based on the `factor`.

```
p <- plot_ly(df,y = ~normalized, color = ~etf_id, type = "box",boxpoints = 'suspectedoutliers')
p
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. By boxpoints, do you mean your actual data points plotted over the boxplots? Something like this `p <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = etf_id, y = normalized)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = etf_id)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor))` ? Then run `p <- ggplotly(p)` to plotly-fy it.

Comment: yes I mean them.but I want to use plotly() instead of ggplotly()